# FOSRestBundle - Allow only json + xml and default to json if no other requested

Tags: php, symfony, fosrestbundle

Could someone show me a reference configuration of FOSRestBundle that will only allow json + xml and willd default to json if "Accepted" or "Content-Type" has not been set.

My goal is to drop the templates html support and all other unnecessary formats (in my case).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Got it.

```
# app/config/config.yml
# ...
fos_rest:
    routing_loader:
        default_format: json
        include_format: true
    param_fetcher_listener: force
    body_listener: true
    allowed_methods_listener: true
    view:
        view_response_listener: 'force'
        formats:
            json: true
            xml: true
    format_listener:
        rules:
            - { path: '^/api', priorities: ['json', 'xml'], fallback_format: json, prefer_extension: true }

sensio_framework_extra:
    view:    { annotations: false }
    router:  { annotations: true }
# ...
```